# Android app crashes when I quit the app if Parcelised data has been used at some point, even though that data was successfully Parcelized

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I have a strange crash on both the `Genymotion` Android simulator and my `Huawei Nexus 6P`.  I have a screenshot that I am sending to another `Anko Component` successfully  - obviously it is Parcelable:

```
@Parcelize
data class ColourBoardScreenShot(var screenshot: @RawValue BitmapDrawable) : Parcelable
```

However, if I take the screenshot and anytime later quit the app by pressing the circle button at the bottom of the screen the app crashes with the following stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: uk.co.davechambers.pegboard, PID: 2292
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4cdb04c
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1477)
at uk.co.davechambers.pegboard.models.ColourBoardScreenShot.writeToParcel(ColourBoardScreenShot.kt:0)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1496)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1402)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:154)
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1307)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:617)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1496)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1402)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3633)
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3773)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT**:

If I try and replace the `ColourBoardScreenShot` by using a plugin to generate the Parcelize code I get `Unresolved reference` on `read` and `write`:

```
data class ColourBoardScreenShot(var screenshot: @RawValue BitmapDrawable) : Parcelable {
constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
        source.read[@kotlinx.android.parcel.RawValue] BitmapDrawable ()
)

override fun describeContents() = 0

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
    write[@kotlinx.android.parcel.RawValue] BitmapDrawable (screenshot)
}

companion object {
    @JvmField
    val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<ColourBoardScreenShot> = object : Parcelable.Creator<ColourBoardScreenShot> {
        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): ColourBoardScreenShot = ColourBoardScreenShot(source)
        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ColourBoardScreenShot?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What makes you say “even though that data was successfully Parcelized”? How do you know? It sure looks like parceling does not succeed.

Comment: @Ben P The data is an image and that image is passed to another view successfully. The problem occurs when the app is quit

Comment: How do you pass it to the other view? Parceling in Android involves a number of shortcuts in situations where no IPC needs to be done. For instance, if you put a `Parcelable` object into an activity's `onSaveInstanceState()` bundle and then rotate your device you will find that you can successfully retrieve that `Parcelable` object from the `savedInstanceState` bundle even though it was never actually parceled. I suspect that hitting the phone's home button is the first time your object actually tries to serialize itself into a Parcel.

Comment: @BenP.I just put it in the bundle `bundle.putParcelable ("screenshot", screenShot)` then retrieve it in the other view.

Comment: Chances are very good that the system isn't actually serializing the data in that case, and is instead simply keeping it in-memory since you're working within the same process. I know the whole point of `@Parcelize` is that you don't have to manually write out the parceling code, but you can try to intentionally write bad parceling code for this class (maybe just throw an exception) and see if the bundle still works. I suspect it will.

Comment: @BenP.Thanks for the help.  I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `ColourBoardScreenShot` to the following:

```
@Parcelize
data class ColourBoardScreenShot(var screenshot: ByteArray) : Parcelable
```

So instead of `@RawValue BitmapDrawable` I use `ByteArray` and the crash stopped.